# Doctrine2 INDEX By Array Format

Tags: doctrine-orm

I am trying to fetch data using doctrine 2, so that the array result has id in index of the array and the other column as value to that index.

```
The format I am trying to get is :

    [country_id] = country
```

I am not sure if that is even possible.

```
$dql = "SELECT c.country FROM User\Entity\Country c INDEX BY c.country_id";
        $dq = $em->createQuery($dql);
        $countries = $dq->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);        
        $em->clear();
```

**Current Result:**

> [0] => Array
>       (
>           [country] => Afghanistan
>       )
>
> [1] => Array
>       (
>           [country] => Aland Islands
>       )
>
> [2] => Array
>       (
>           [country] => Albania
>       )

**Required Result:**

> [0] => Afghanistan
>
> [1]  => Aland Islands
>
> [2] => Albania

Comment: Maybe create another array and fill it with values of the result array

Comment: Well looping around is always an option.. thanks btw

Comment: ,well yes if you don't find a proper way to do with directly with doctrine, you can always consider this option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how to do it your way, i know how to do it as i am used to :

```
$conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
$sql = "SELECT c.country FROM Country c;";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

The result should be a single array without having array inside array as the fetch_column return only value of the column and not array with index.

## Edit :

To keep the index by you will have to create a custom hydrator :

```
protected function _hydrateAll()
    {
        return $this->_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    }
```

This way you will keep the index by and using the FETCH_COLUMN at the same time.

I only put the code for the function because the link below give you all you need the part i changed is the FETCH_COLUMN all should be correct.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#custom-hydration-modes

Comment: But I need the country id in the array index

Comment: ah sorry wait i update the answer with the right solution, since index by is not available in this case with sql basically you need a custom hydrator